# Directive should take data from template OR from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angularjs. I have a directive that shows countdown to `endDate`. Everything works fine with a hardcoded value:

```
var endDate = new Date("2013-11-26T10:00:00Z");
```

But I can not manage how to dynamicaly pass a value to directive from controller or from rendered template, since there are two use cases of my directive.

**CountDownDirective.js:**

```
app.directive("countdown", ["$window", function($window) {

return {
    restrict: "EA",
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        function countdown(){
            var endDate = new Date("2013-11-26T10:00:00Z"); //hardcode
            //some logic...
        }

        countdown();
    }
}
}]);
```

**SomeController.js:**

```
app.controller("SomeController", ["$scope", '$rootScope', "APIService", 
function($scope, $rootScope, APIService){

    APIService.get('end_data').then(function(response){
        $scope.end_data = response;
        // response is "2013-11-26T10:00:00Z"
    });
    //some logic...
}
]);
```

**template_one.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <div countdown>...</div>
</div>
```

**template_two.html:**

```
<div countdown end-date="2013-11-26T10:00:00Z">...</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: please show some code for your controller and directive please.  otherwise, it is impossible to tell how you are current attempting to bind the data between them.

Comment: numerous ways to do it ...provide sample of code outlining problem

Comment: I made an update, so you can check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass it via scope. Consider having in html:

```
<div your_directive 
    message="message">
</div>
```

where message is variable in scope which you can set by controller:

```
$scope.message
```

Then you would have in your directive:

```
app.directive("your_directive", function() {
return {
    restrict : "A",
    scope: {
        message: "="
    },
```

then you can access this value inside your link function like this:

```
scope.message
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what if we have no controller, but only attribute: `<div your_directive message="2013-11-26T10:00:00Z">...</div>`?

Comment: you should still be able to access it in link function, shouldn't you?

Comment: Now I'm looking at your edit. So, add scope with value {endData: "="} and you should be able to access your attribute.

Comment: It works if we pass a variable from scope (using controller). Otherwise error is raised: `Error: [$parse:syntax]`. I think passing variable from attribute requires `"@"`

Comment: that's also ok... I just thought based on your title you need to access it with controller as well...